# History.js to properly works with modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, history.js

I wonder if anyone has a better solution to my problem. I'm trying to implement History.js to also works with modal popup. The same technique used in Pinterest if you try to click any of the pins the popup shows and if you close the popup or click back arrow of browser the url change back to root. Try to forward then backward the browser history and thats what Im after for. heres my code so far.

```
$('.thumbnail').on('click',function(e){
    var urlPath = $(this).attr('href');

    //ajax call here then update content of the popup and pushState after ajax successful
    History.pushState({ "action":"show_popup" } , response.pageTitle, urlPath); //change url to website.com/post/123456
    $('#popup').popup('show'); //show popup
});

History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function() { 
        var State = History.getState();
        if(State.action == "show_popup"){
            //call to show popup
        }else{
            //call to hide all popup
        }
});

//change back the url when popup close
$('#popup').bind('closed',function(){
    // change the url back to website.com/feeds/
    History.back();
});
```

My problem is how do I tell when to show or hide the popup when I forward/back the browser?